# Working Gmail notifier for Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, email, gmail

I tried the various gmail notifiers offered in the repo and in gnome shell extensions, but I can't find one that actually works with this version of Ubuntu.

My workaround is to run Wavebox minimized, but it's pretty heavy just to use for a notifier. But it does have an advantage that it only shows unread mail count for important mail.

Just to make it clear, I am looking for an indicator that sits on the panel and tells you if you have unread mail.

In KDE desktop, the Chrome icon is capable of displaying unread mail count (when Chrome is running), just like it does in Windows, but in Gnome and Cinnamon, it doesn't seem capable of that. If anyone happens to know how to get the Chrome icon to indicate unread mail, in Gnome, that would be an ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

Mailnag works.

To install the standard Mailnag for your version of Ubuntu just do:

```
sudo apt-get install mailnag
mailnagconfig
```

To install the latest and greatest: there is a its `ppa` available as well:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pulb/mailnag
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mailnag
mailnagconfig
```

Then install the [Gnome shell extension here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/886/mailnag/).

If it still doesn't pull your unread mail, make sure that you have installed mailnag-goa-plugin, and that you have set up your google account in Gnome online accounts. 
https://github.com/pulb/mailnag-goa-plugin

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Could you please [edit] that answer and include the actual commands to execute?  Then leave a comment @Fabby and I'll come back and upvote instead of the downvote you just received.  **:-(**

Comment: @Fabby how's it look now?

Comment: Your version was good enough to remove the downvote. **;-)** However, could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1154549/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the *readability* of your answers in the future as after my edit it's worthy of an upvote as well... **;-)** If you want to discuss why I did things the way I did, please [see me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room?_=1613243665&_=1289574655)